Nationl Instruments PXI-5412 setup in C
I am trying to use the example codes that I found in the niFgen library in order to troubleshoot another program my lab has written. Specifically, I wanted to know what I should enter for the line
strcpy(Resource, "PXI1Slot2");

In my case, the PXI I am using is a PXI-5412, and it is located in slot 5, but I cannot seem to figure out what I should put in this line so that the program can find the library. Everything I try causes the code to error out and crash. For reference, I have included the file that is causing me trouble. Any help would be much appreciated!

"For reference, I have included the file..." Where did you show that file? What errors do you get? Please include complete and exact error messages as text in the question.
